# Strapi admin page not loading after deploy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, strapi

After deploying my strapi app to heroku, the admin panel is not loading after logging in. There's a loading circle for a second and then a blank page appears. On localhost everything works fine.
After login, when I open the console I get this error:

```
TypeError: (0 , s.default) is not a function
```

[image: this error]

The API works fine. I'm using MongoDB for the database.

Here's my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "czarogrod-backend-strapi",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cloudinary": "^1.32.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "strapi": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-admin": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-connector-mongoose": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-utils": "^3.6.8",
    "video-react": "0.16.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "2474ae8d-dfcf-46d2-9167-e53366ff5737"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Here's `config/server.js`:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env("HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
  port: env.int("PORT", 1337),
  admin: {
    autoopen: false,
    auth: {
      secret: env("ADMIN_JWT_SECRET", "7c50c2e280dc173164bccb85852308f7"),
    },
  },
});
```

Here's `config/database.js`:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: "mongoose",
      settings: {
        uri: env("DATABASE_URI"),
      },
      options: {
        ssl: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

`config/env/production/database.js` looks the same.

My `env` variables are the same as in production.

Thank you for any help in advance